# Chrome extension - injecting script and running it on inactive tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have Chrome extension that injects a script into a page on load. If it is a certain page, it opens a set of links on that page in new tabs and when those tabs are loaded the injected script submits a form on the tab. The issue is that the injection is not happening on tabs that are not current. It works only on the current tab.

A simplified version of my code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Doing stuff",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Bot"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*.url.com/*",
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.js :

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {


    if(changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

        try {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
                file: 'inject.js'
            });

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(" extension cannot run on the chrome:// page ")
        }
    } 

})
```

inject.js :

```
(function() {

    function page1() {

        links = document.querySelectorAll("a.link_class");
        for(var link in links) {
            link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
            link.click();
        }
    }

    function page2() {
        // this does not run in tabs that are inactive
        // in order to make it run, i have to click in the inactive tab and reload it manually
        document.querySelector("input[name='field_to_update']").text = "setting the field value";
        button = document.querySelector("input[name='button']");
        button.click();
    }

    if(document.querySelector("div.page1") != null) {
        page1();
    } else {
        page2();
    }
})();
```

Comment: can you use iframes instead of new tabs? Might be quicker/easier to use tampermonkey than an extension for this sort of thing...

Comment: The injection per se most likely actually happens, which you can verify by adding console.log at the start of inject.js or by inspecting the "content scripts" panel in devtools of the inactive tab. The problem is probably that the site waits for its tab to become active before activating the form. Depending on how the form is organized you can collect and submit its data directly in your code.

Comment: Have you been able to find the solution to your problem? I am struggling with the same issue.